# Cannot upgrade to Angular 6, invalid range

Tags: angular, npm, angular6

I am upgrading to Angular 6

[Following the upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io/), I encounter the following problem:

```
> ng update @angular/core                
Invalid range: ">=2.1.0"
```

...and that's all I have. No other warnings, or any other description. In my project, there is no match for the ">=2.1.0" string either.

`ng -v` results:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.0
Node: 9.4.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 4.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router, tsc-wrapped

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.0
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.0
@angular/cli                      6.0.0
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.0
@schematics/angular               0.6.0
@schematics/update                0.6.0
rxjs                              6.1.0
typescript                        2.3.2
webpack                           4.6.0
```

**Update:** Thing's that did not work:

- updating everything manually to the latest version
- updating rxjs manually
- updating typescript to 2.7.2 and then to 2.8.3
- trying to `ng update --all`
- `npm install @angular/compiler@6.0.0`

After each of these steps, the angular/core would not update with the error stated above.

Now i have updated my project, ng -v shows the following:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Node: 9.4.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
OS: linux x64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Angular: 6.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
... cli, compiler, core                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

Package                             Version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
@angular-devkit/architect           0.6.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
@angular-devkit/build-angular       0.6.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer     0.6.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
@angular-devkit/core                0.6.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
@angular-devkit/schematics          0.6.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
@angular/animations                 5.2.10
@angular/common                     5.2.10
@angular/compiler-cli               5.2.10
@angular/forms                      5.2.10
@angular/http                       5.2.10
@angular/platform-browser           5.2.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   5.2.10
@angular/platform-server            5.2.10
@angular/router                     5.2.10
@ngtools/webpack                    6.0.0
@schematics/angular                 0.6.0
@schematics/update                  0.6.0
rxjs                                6.1.0
typescript                          2.8.3
webpack                             4.6.0
```

But despite the fact it shows 6.0, the project fails to run (errors in angular/core package), and executing the command `ng update @angular/core` still yields the same error message.

**Update2:**
I am using the angular 4.0 compatible version of https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin as the project base. There are a lot of modifications on it though.

**Update3:"**
After updating everything manually to 6.0, and @angular/core to 5.2, the problem still persist (Invalid range: ">=2.1.0") the package.json is the following:

```
{
  "name": "-------",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "---------",
  "author": "-------",
  "homepage": "-------",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "-----"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "-------"
  },
  "license": "---",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "changelog": "standard-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:hmr": "ng serve --hmr",
    "start:aot": "ng serve --aot",
    "start:prod": "ng serve --prod",
    "start:prod:aot": "ng serve --prod --aot",
    "build": "npm run clean:dist && ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod",
    "build:prod:aot": "npm run build:prod -- --aot",
    "build:ci": "npm run build:prod && npm run build:prod:aot",
    "test": "ng test -sr",
    "test:coverage": "npm run clean:coverage && ng test -sr -cc",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/app/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:coverage": "npm run rimraf -- coverage",
    "docs:deploy": "wintersmith build -C docs && gh-pages -d docs/build",
    "docs:serve": "wintersmith preview -C docs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.10",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
    "amcharts3": "github:amcharts/amcharts3",
    "ammap3": "github:amcharts/ammap3",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.5",
    "angular2-datatable": "0.6.0",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "chart.js": "1.1.1",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "chroma-js": "1.3.3",
    "ckeditor": "4.6.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.3.1",
    "google-maps": "3.2.1",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "leaflet": "0.7.7",
    "leaflet-map": "0.2.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.6",
    "ng2-completer": "1.3.1",
    "ng2-handsontable": "0.48.0",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "4.0.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.0.3",
    "ng2-tree": "2.0.0-alpha.5",
    "ngx-uploader": "4.2.4",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.10",
    "zone.js": "0.8.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.10",
    "@types/fullcalendar": "2.7.40",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.41",
    "@types/jquery.slimscroll": "1.3.30",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.61",
    "@types/node": "6.0.69",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "gh-pages": "0.12.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "standard-changelog": "1.0.1",
    "stylelint": "7.10.1",
    "ts-node": "2.1.2",
    "tslint": "5.2.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "4.0.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "0.9.6",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "typogr": "0.6.6",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "wintersmith": "2.2.5",
    "wintersmith-sassy": "1.1.0"
  }
}
```

**Update4:**
This is an interesting lead from the github thread by [Bjeaurn](https://github.com/Bjeaurn):

> In regards to the Invalid range: xxx errors, I've taken a quick peek
>   at the @angular-devkit/schematics repo to see where the error was
>   thrown and what was actually happening.
>
> The error is thrown at
>   https://github.com/angular/devkit/blob/master/packages/schematics/update/update/index.ts#L41
>
> If I look at the surrounding function, seems that it's expecting
>   semver versioned packages only, and no logical (by the lack of a
>   better term?) versioning.

This might be the core problem, but I still fail to see how to fix this :\

Comment: found the issue on github too: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10621

Comment: I also got a vague error from it after updating it  but not like yours, try removing node_modules and retry to npm install

Comment: thanks, but that did not solve it.

Comment: Another option is to create new project using latest cli version and then copy/compare configuration.

Comment: @kemsky I think deleting the node_modules folder and a new npm install basicly the same: and it does yield the same results.

Comment: Can you upload your package.json please

Comment: @Borquaye I updated my description with it.

Comment: https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues/1679 the same error

Comment: @oCcSking that's my thread there as well :) The problem is, that a clean project pulled from their repository is update-able with the method described there, but it does not work on my specific project.

Comment: I would migrate manually from a new empty project

Comment: @MurhafSousli that will be the case if everything else fails. But I really would like to avoid that, as the project is **extended deeply, to a structural level**, and I really would not want to do a minimum 1 week work for just one bug if possible. If nothing helps, must do it though :\

Comment: Can you provide the package.json of your Angular 4 version .in the docs they mentioned upgrading to next major version is better than upgrading by skipping a major version....instead of 4-6 make it stable at 4-5 , then 5-6, if possible please create sample repo!!!

Comment: @AmpatiHareesh the package.json I provided is in the stable 5.2 version. I was able to upgrade 4 -> 5, but unable to upgrade 5 -> 6 (or even 4 -> 6).
I am sadly unable to publish the code by legal obligations :(

Comment: I dove into the source code to determine what was going on using your package.json from above. I found the same issue that is mentioned in your 4th update, along with determining the package that was causing the issue. I opened up a bug in the devkit around this, so hopefully they'll resolve it soon. https://github.com/angular/devkit/issues/889

Comment: Should be solved via https://github.com/angular/devkit/pull/901/commits/6cdd4f12afc7882f0db6ecd97f26802ff0526e35

Comment: Yurzui please provide this as an answer so I can award you the points. That update solved my case.

Comment: True  :) great one yurzui ,yes ForestG +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally!!! Solved, actually halfway, because of the internal dependencies mentioned in package.json.

> Went through all of the errors below one after the other

```
Invalid Range: ">=2.1.0"
Invalid Range:">=2.0.0|| >=4.0.0-beta"
Incompatible peer dependencies 
Invalid Range:">=4.0.0
```

> Because of the modules

```
ng2-completer
angular-table
ng2-smart-table
ng2-handsontable
ng2-slim-loading-bar
@ngx-translate/core 
@ngx-translate/http-loader,
```

Few of them can be upgraded, which mentions 6.0.0 angular version as their peer dependencies

But few of them still using the old version 2 | 4

By resolving all the peer dependencies, able to resolve the error(omitted which are not upgraded)

PS: If at all if the external dependencies that you are depending upon doesn't use the new version, look for alternative !!!

**Edited**:

> **This will get resolved by upgrading to angular 6.0.1, as**

angular/devkit has been updated --> packages/schematics/update/update/index.ts

which fixed angular-cli as well

Ref : https://github.com/angular/devkit/pull/901/commits/6cdd4f12afc7882f0db6ecd97f26802ff0526e35 (as **yurzui** ,ForestG mentioned)

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thank you for your time! But I have a hard time understanding what you did. What did you update? How? In What order? What were the exact commands? `ng update ng2-completer` right away fails with the original (Invalid range...) error for me.

Comment: Here, few of the modules have a constraint to use less than 6 version, and actually order is not important here ,becoz dependencies can be updated like npm install --save yourmodule@latest ...

Comment: And the syntax issue of using >= vs ^, as Daniel W Strimpel mentioned

Comment: Will comment each module version and it's supported Angular version and the peer dependencies. Before that , in the meantime you can remove the mentioned modules and do the upgrade after that... add those dependencies to your application

Comment: Use ng update @angular/core to update after uninstalling the mentioned modules

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! I will definityl look into it after the weekend, but I am on vacation from now on.

Comment: Hey  I am sorry but I have updated all of the stated dependecies, and still get the exact same error.

Comment: Yes the error happens because,1. few of them are  using 2-4 not above.. 2.if you look at ngx-translate peer dependencies  , the angular version mentioned as >=6.0.0 and this too causes the issue as it looks for ^6.0.0

Comment: Hence , pls try to look the peer dependencies of the modules which have been developed using angular ,remove them and after upgrading , install them again

Comment: angular 2- datatable, angular 2- csv module also includes in the above list

Comment: Actually, updating to angular 6.0.1 was what solved this for me. The exact cause was this bug: https://github.com/angular/devkit/pull/901/commits/6cdd4f12afc7882f0db6ecd97f26802ff0526e35 that got fixed with it. I appreciate the effort you put in in this matter, but the base problem was a bug, not the dependency versions themselves.

Comment: +1, Yes it's a bug , with version syntax , that's the reason provided the workarounds :) , but this has been changed 3 days back though :)

Answer (score 2):

After alot of research, I have come up with following solution and got success in updating my local project to Angular 6.0.1:

1. npm install @angular/{animations,common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router}@'6.0.1'
2. ng update rxjs
3. npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
4. ng update @angular/core
5. ng update @angular/material
6. npm install typescript@'>=2.7.0 <2.8.0'

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue here, but my "invalid range" was different:

```
Invalid range: ">=2.3.1 <3.0.0||>=4.0.0"
```

After struggling for a few hours, trying to narrow down what dependency was causing that, I found out that I had two "ng-bootstrap" dependencies by mistake :(

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts": "^1.0.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    ...
    "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",       <<< WRONG!!
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
```

So, after removing `ng-bootstrap` with `npm`, `ng update @angular/core @angular/compiler-cli rxjs` went through nicely! :)

Comment: thanks for the help, but removing it did not solve my case.